# Ring of functions is finitely generated in a quasi compact variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Suppose $(V, \mathcal{O}_V)$ be a quasi compact algebraic variety over $k$. Is $ \Gamma (V, \mathcal{O}(V))$ always finitely generated as an $k$ algebra ?

Comment: Is an algebraic variety necessarily of finite type over $k$ for you?

Comment: No it is just a quasicompact space with a sheaf of regular functions that is locally isomorphic to an affine variety

Comment: What is an affine variety for you? Just an separated affine scheme? It should be of finite type over $k$, I guess.

Comment: Yes. We haven’t been introduced to schemes. But an affine variety is just zero set of polynomials in A_n with the usual structure sheaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. The following note by Vakil gives a 3 dimensional counterexample:

http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/nonfg.pdf